# What's the best practice for storing references of Google Cloud Storage objects in my own database?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

My typical implementation for persisting images/videos/audios is to store them on Google Cloud Storage and store those public download URLs in my database. So let's say I use MongoDB then the saved user document would look like the one below

```js
{
  _id: ObjectId('...'),
  username: 'Karen',
  photoUrl: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-name/file-path'
}
```

But I recently encountered some limitations to this approach.

1. I can't prevent unauthorized users to access those files.
2. Since the download URLs are hardcoded with direct access to Google Cloud Storage, I can't use Load Balancer or CDN.

The solution I came up with is to store only the bucket name and the file path in the database and whenever the client requests a resource to my own server endpoint with the bucket name and the file path, checks if the request came from the authenticated user and retrieves the file from Google Cloud Storage and send the file response instead of the download URL. In this case, the download URL becomes my own server endpoint such as

```
https://my-server.com/bucket-name/file-path
```

with Authorization header for authentication.
But this approach increases my server bandwidth and so cost.

Is there a better solution? What's the recommended way to store and retrieve files on Google Cloud Storage?

Comment: Have your app return [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) to user for download the file. You must generate new one for each request, using original url from Mongo as location. Docs example [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best pattern is to use [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).

Like that, the user performs a request to your server, you check the authorization and you return a signed URL to download the content directly from the Cloud Storage. With this option, you save bandwidth from your app server and you gain authentication.

You have a similar version to use [signed URL with CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs/using-signed-urls), with a programmatic part at the end. I never tested it, but it seems answering your question.